# How can I format my date to fill in a datetime field with MySQL and Python (MySQLdb)?

Tags: python, mysql, datetime, mysql-python

I've been trying to fill in my database with tests that are made every minute for different clients but haven't been able to format my date to go in the `datetime` field called time.

The format is supposed to be `YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS`

```
import MySQLdb as mdb 
import datetime                                                
con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'testuser', 'test623', 'xymon');
now = str((datetime.datetime.now()).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
print '#'+now+'#'
with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO download(time, client1,client2,client3,client4) VALUES('%s',1500,2500,70000,100000)") , (now)
    con.commit()
```

What happens is the value goes in the datebase but being wrong just goes in as `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

Comment: @Duikboot isn't that what I've done on line 4?

Comment: I think you can insert a datetime object instead of a string into the query: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html

Comment: I've tried replacing `str((datetime.datetime.now()).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))` by the same without casting as a string and also just `datetime.datetime.now()` and I get the same error (that last one returns milliseconds so it seems normal)

Comment: Do yourself a favour and use sqlalchemy

Comment: Not my choice to make unfortunately, I've got to use what is already on the system.

Comment: You have the supply 'now' to cur.execute call and no quotes around the %s
 cur.execute("INSERT INTO download(time, client1,client2,client3,client4) VALUES(%s,1500,2500,70000,100000)", now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to supply `now` to the `cur.execute` call and no quotes around the `%s` which gives :

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO download(time, client1,client2,client3,client4) VALUES(%s,1500,2500,70000,100000)", now)
```